# Using GDAL translate with VRT - merge error in overlap creates black 

Tags: gdal, merge, gdalwarp, gdal-translate, gdal-merge

I have a series of hi resolution multispectral images from Maxar's WV2 in .NTF form. I am trying to stitch tiles together to create a single image, and I've been having a lot of trouble. I initially tried to use gdal merge with this command

```
gdal_merge.py -o out.NTF in1.NTF in2.NTF
```

but once created, as soon as I tried to open it in ArcGIS Pro, it said that there was no coordinate system defined. I tried adding the coordinate system using ArcGIS Pro's tool, but it failed.

I then moved on to trying to use gdal BuildVRT and gdal translate together instead. However, I got an error saying that it didn't support ungeoreferenced images. After reading through [gdalbuildvrt does not support ungeoreferenced image](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/417843), I decided to use gdalwarp to try to convert them to the affine geotransformation. That seemed to work, so I went back to create the VRT and then the merged set using this Python script (files is a list of the files generated by the gdalwarp command).

```
vrt = gdal.BuildVRT("merged.vrt", files)
gdal.Translate("merged.NTF", vrt)
vrt = None
```

That seemed to work, but when I opened it up in ArcGIS Pro, the area where the two tiles had overlapped completely black. After some research, I found that this might be because of the [order of the files in gdal.BuildVRT()](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/5070). I tested it out by switching the order of the files and regenerating the VRT and final merged .NTF, and sure enough, the block box of the overlap was in the inverse spot.

How do I correct this?

I've tried so much to try to get this working and I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Perhaps you can handle the transparency with some combination of srcnodata, vrrnodata, and addalpha https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html.

Comment: @user30184 thanks for your response - I'm new to gdal and I'm trying my best to understand what these flags will do. I'm a little confused as to what value I would give srcnodata and vrrnodata? I've looked through the metadata of my original files and they do not have a NODATA field for any of the bands. Would it just be assumed that this is 0?